# Resize grid in the world based on number of turtles (input) and link specific breeds together

Tags: netlogo

I would need to visualize the below turtles (from three different breeds) in a squared grid where links are only between turtles from the same breed, except for breeds types2 and types3, that can be also linked to each other.
So what I would like to have is a 2D grid where the number of turtles per each type is

```
40% of type1
40% of type2
20% of type3
```

(in total 100 turtles).

```
  set-default-shape types1 "circle"
  set-default-shape types2 "circle"
  set-default-shape types3 "triangle"

  ask n-of 100 patches [ sprout-types1 1 ]
  ask n-of (100 * 0.4) types1 [set breed types2]
  ask n-of (100 * 0.2) types1 [set breed types3]
```

the values are ok but the turtles are 'free' in the world, not displayed on a grid.
How can I display them into a grid and link them based on the above conditions?

This answer [Different types of turtles in a lattice grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165300/different-types-of-turtles-in-a-lattice-grid) has provided some help on this, but the resize of the grid and the number of turtles are not the expected ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resize the world before creating agents.
That is, from the perspective of the code's workflow: if you want to have `n` agents, then `n` is first and foremost the number of patches. Then, once this is the case, all patches will `sprout`.

You need the [`resize-world` command](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#resize-world).

You mentioned that you want to have 100 turtles, that is 100 patches, that is a 10x10 world.

This means that you could do:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  
  resize-world 0 9 0 9   ; This creates a 10x10 world.
  set-patch-size 30
  
  ask patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set shape "circle"
      set size 0.5
    ]
  ]
end
```

The code above works as long as you are happy for your world to be the size of exactly 100 patches, given that the size = 100 is hard-coded.

You might want to think about some way to accomodate a change in the number of agents.
For example, the approach below works as long as the number of agents is the perfect square of an integer:

```
globals [
  n-agents
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set n-agents 100

  let side-length n-agents ^ (1 / 2) - 1
  resize-world 0 side-length 0 side-length
  set-patch-size 30
  
  ask patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set shape "circle"
      set size 0.5
    ]
  ]
end
```

After all the point is that the shape of the world in NetLogo can only be a square or a rectangle; i.e. you cannot have a NetLogo world that is made of a prime number of patches (only exception being a world whose `world-height` and/or `world-width` equal 1).

So, in order to have your code be the most accomodating to changes in `n`, you could come up with more elaborated steps that resize the world based on `n` so that it gives you `n` patches even when `n` is not a perfect square; but for example, unless you are happy to have a monodimensional world, you can never have 53 patches. However, since you are talking of grids, I **think** this shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help, Matteo. Since I have three breeds, how should I correctly assign the percentage of them to the patch? I have tried to keep ask n-of but it seems that the pct returned are wrong

Comment: @Math The example I gave you brings you to the point of having a square world with one agent for each patch. Everything about setting breeds and links should remain exactly the same from this point on (of course you would have to substitute `sprout 1` with `sprout-types1 1` if you want to recycle your previous code, so that you will be able to `ask n-of (100 * 0.4) types1`)

Comment: Thank you so much, Matteo. I actually tried as follows:   `ask patches [ sprout-types1 1]
  ask n-of (100 * 0.4) types1 [set breed types1 set color red]
  ask n-of (100 * 0.4) types1 [set breed types2 set color blue]
  ask n-of (100 * 0.2) types1 [set breed types3 set color green]` but the numbers are still wrong :/

Comment: @Math are you sure it is the numbers that are wrong or is it just the colors that are wrong? In your example, you change a random 40 types1 turtles to types1 with a color. Then you pick a random 40 types1 again but those could very well include the ones whose color your initially changed. It would be better to just change all types1's to red and then continue on with the rest.

Comment: I was counting the turtles based on their color, so the numbers were wrong. My apologies! Thanks a million. Using ask for each type to separately set the colors worked! Many thanks LeirsW